# How to keep ggplot font size constant when varying figure width

Tags: fonts, r, knitr

I have different figures across my document with different width. I set the the font size for all `ggplot`s globally with `theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(text=element_text(family="Palatino", size=20)))` but I want to set the figure width with the `knitr` option `out.width='` in the preamble of each figure chunk. The problem is this results in different effective font size to be typeset by `LaTeX`. The solution of course would be to manually set the font size differently for each chunk.

I just wonder if there's a smarter solution (without using dev=`tikz`) so to:

1) Set the font size once and for all plots;
2) Maintain the possibility to set the width size locally for each figure.

Please consider the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

<<set-options, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center', dev='pdf', cache=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, progress = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(text=element_text(family="Palatino", size=20)))
@           

<<<prepare-data,  include=FALSE>>=
data1.df <- data.frame(Plant = c("Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant2", "Plant2", 
    "Plant2"), Type = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Axis1 = c(0.2, -0.4, 0.8, -0.2, -0.7, 
    0.1), Axis2 = c(0.5, 0.3, -0.1, -0.3, -0.1, -0.8))

data2.df <- data.frame(Plant = c("Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant2", "Plant2", 
    "Plant2"), Type = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Axis1 = c(20, 40, 80, 20, 70, 
    0.1), Axis2 = c(50, 30, 10, 30, 10, 80))
@ 

<<Fig1, fig.cap='Large', fig.env='figure', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE, out.width='.62\\textwidth'>>=


ggplot(data1.df, aes(x = Axis1, y = Axis2, shape = Plant, color = Type)) + geom_point(size = 5) +  annotate("text", x=0.4, y=0.0, label="Label", fontface="italic") + theme(legend.position="none")


@ 

<<Fig2, fig.cap='Small', subfig.cap=c("First","Second"), fig.env='figure*', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE, out.width='.32\\textwidth'>>=


ggplot(data1.df, aes(x = Axis1, y = Axis2, shape = Plant, color = Type)) + geom_point(size = 5) +  annotate("text", x=0.4, y=0.0, label="Label", fontface="italic") + theme(legend.position="none")

ggplot(data2.df, aes(x = Axis1, y = Axis2, shape = Plant, color = Type)) + geom_point(size = 5) + theme(legend.position="none")


@ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is no smart solution. I always set `out.width` for individual code chunks.

Answer (score 2):

You could supply the length that you want `out.width` to be relative to as a constant in `R` and call that in your plots. You can find the length of \textwidth by complining your .tex file with `\the\textwidth`, which for the `article` class with `[letter]` is 345 points (about 4.7917 inches). Then you supply fig.width with a number times your constant.

However, doing this will also require that you set `fig.height` since the aspect ratio is not constrained by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

<<set-options, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center', dev='pdf', cache=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, progress = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(text=element_text(family="Palatino", size=20)))
@

<<prepare-data,  include=FALSE>>=
data1.df <- data.frame(Plant = c("Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant2", "Plant2",
    "Plant2"), Type = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Axis1 = c(0.2, -0.4, 0.8, -0.2, -0.7,
    0.1), Axis2 = c(0.5, 0.3, -0.1, -0.3, -0.1, -0.8))

data2.df <- data.frame(Plant = c("Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant1", "Plant2", "Plant2",
    "Plant2"), Type = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Axis1 = c(20, 40, 80, 20, 70,
    0.1), Axis2 = c(50, 30, 10, 30, 10, 80))
@

<<sizes, include=FALSE>>=
textwidth <- 4.7917 # Default \textwidth with \usepackage[letter]{article}
@

<<Fig1, fig.cap='Large', fig.env='figure', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE, fig.width=.62*textwidth, fig.height=.52*textwidth>>=


ggplot(data1.df, aes(x = Axis1, y = Axis2, shape = Plant, color = Type)) + geom_point(size = 5) +  annotate("text", x=0.4, y=0.0, label="Label", fontface="italic") + theme(legend.position="none")


@

<<Fig2, fig.cap='Small', subfig.cap=c("First","Second"), fig.env='figure*', message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, error=FALSE, fig.width=.32*textwidth, fig.height=.27*textwidth>>=


ggplot(data1.df, aes(x = Axis1, y = Axis2, shape = Plant, color = Type)) + geom_point(size = 5) +  annotate("text", x=0.4, y=0.0, label="Label", fontface="italic") + theme(legend.position="none")

ggplot(data2.df, aes(x = Axis1, y = Axis2, shape = Plant, color = Type)) + geom_point(size = 5) + theme(legend.position="none")


@

\end{document}
```

[image]